# Angular+Bootstrap broken layout only on iPhone

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 8+Bootstrap 4.3.1 application hosted on a VPS and accedes only by IP.It works fine on my phone (Android 9+ Chrome) also on my dev machine(Windows 10+Opera 60)

[image]

but not working on client devices (iPhone 8,iPhone 10),tested in Safari,Firefox and Chrome with same results:

[image]

layout seems broken,not all data is shown.I tested on my computer browser console,no error,all works,I don't have a iPhone so I don't know how to debug that.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: you need to show the code that is rendering this as it could be many things

Comment: found the problem:the layout is based on a array,before creating it,something like that return false on iPhone,and true on Android: DATE1.getTime() === DATE2.getTime()); instead I compared year+month+day.a possible time insertion(no time needed here),regional date time settings,etc.thanks

Answer (score 1):

In this stage, I would prefer two ways,

1. You can debug from the desktop using dev tool chrome browser with iPhone mode,

[image]

2. In the server, you can have REST API response interceptor using which you can log the response to the file in the server and debug further.

Comment: Hi.using dev tools with iPhone mode works fine in my computer,no error in console 
:( .thanks